# How to modify Laravel 5 default authentication system

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-5

I am using the default Laravel 5 authentication system. I would like to simply add a check that verifies that the user is using a school email account (I am writing this for my University). So for example I want to make sure they are using **@harvard.edu**, and not **@gmail.com**. If they are not using the correct email type, I want to add an error to the `$errors` variable, and print that along with the the other possible errors on the registration form.

It appears that the actual validation occurs in Registrar.php. I am assuming I will have to add something to the email portion of the validator function.

```
public function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
}
```

The other part I am confused about is where the actually error messages are located.

I am new to Laravel, thanks in advance.

Comment: You're using Laravel 4 or 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a custom validation, you can read the documentation at http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#custom-validation-rules . For example, in you case:

```
Validator::extend('email_harvard', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    $segments = explode("@", $value, 2);
    return end($segments) == "harvard.com";
});
```

After that, modify your `validator` rules, change the line:

```
'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
```

to be:

```
'email' => 'required|email|email_harvard|max:255|unique:users',
```

About the error messages, you can read here. In Laravel 5, the validation messages are located at `resources/lang/xx/validation.php` where `xx` is the language code.

Comment: Would i add that Validator::extend in the validator function? @HieuLe

Comment: You should put this code inside a Service Provider in Laravel 5, see [this post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/validator-custom-rule-laravel-5#reply-7355).